# What are the built-in components of Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I know that HDFS and MapReduce are core components of Hadoop. It means if we want to use HBase, we should install it?

Answer (score 0):

you can download the vanilla version of Hadoop which include HDFS and Mapreduce in it from here.
http://apache.mirrors.tds.net/hadoop/common/
Any applications on Hadoop (HBase,Hive,Pig etc) should be installed separately and they require Hadoop libraries. These applications would expect you set a System variable called `$HADOOP_HOME` which will point you to the location of your Hadoop installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing the open source form apache you'd get just the core hadoop components (HDFS, YARN and MapReduce2 on top of it). However there are several distributions of Hadoop (hortonWorks, Cloudera, MapR, IBM BigInsight, Pivotal) that pack more components along it. You can also install Ambari (Also used in HortonWorks) from Apache and it will allow installing Hadoop and quite a few of the other components